# I want to install Ubuntu from Lubuntu/Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, lubuntu, uninstall

I am new to the whole Ubuntu/linux community so I'm sorry if I am a noob, but lately I've had the desire to switch to a linux distro and so I did. I installed lubuntu with dual boot so that I could switch from windows to lubuntu and vice-versa, but now I want to install ONLY Ubuntu on my pc. Can someone help me remove those two OSes (Windows and Lubuntu) and install Ubuntu ?

Comment: Depending on how you partitioned your disk; you could always just boot Lubuntu, format you windows partition and make it your /home partition (ie. use that location to store all your user data). To move your data across you'd have to reboot into a 'live' environment to move the data across (or I'd `cp` [copy] then `diff` [compare to ensure it's perfect) then add it to your file-system-table (/etc/fstab/ so it's used instead of your existing (which you could delete if you need/want space back or keep awhile as a backup) - but it's your choice.  Ubuntu & Lubuntu are ~same with different GUI's

Comment: Some later find they have one application that they must have and it only is Windows. Best to fully back up Windows. Some also later sell system and then it has to have Windows. Back up your data & configuration in Lubuntu, so you do not have to redo everything, unless just a brand new install.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove Windows or Lubuntu. Just allow Ubuntu to use the whole disk in the install process. This will destroy any data you may have on there so back up anything you want to keep first.